# How to receive property from control to model CanJS (define modules)

Tags: javascript, import, module, export, canjs

I have Control with configurable defaults parameters:

```
   define([
  'jquery',
  'can',
  'moment',
  'controls/base',
  'mustache!./becauseYouShopped_view',
  './becauseYouShopped_model',
  'coreMods/clickHistory/v2/clickHistory_model',
  'coreMods/addToFavorite/addToFavorite_control',
], function ($, can, moment, BaseControl, becauseYouShoppedView, BecauseYouShoppedModel, ClickHistoryModel, AddToFavorite) {
  var startDate = moment().subtract(90, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    endDate = moment().add(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

  var BecauseYouShopped = BaseControl({
    defaults: {
      moduleConfigName: 'becauseYouShopped',
      hideRebatePrefix: true,
      rebateAdditionalPrefix: 'Shop and',
      useOldRebateValueWithoutCurrency: true,
      tiered: {
        rebateAdditionalPrefix: 'Shop and earn',
        useOldRebateValueWithoutCurrency: true
      },
      apiParams: {
        start_date: startDate,
        end_date: endDate,
      },
      headingPrefix: 'Because you shop at',
      dataLimitForGetSimilarMerchant: 14,
    }
  }, {
    init: function (element, options) {
      ClickHistoryModel.findOne(options.apiParams).done(function (data) {
        var memberClicksAndOrders = data.attr().response;

        if (memberClicksAndOrders.length) {
          this.shoppedMerchantsInfo = this.getRecentlyShoppedMerchantName(memberClicksAndOrders);

          if (this.shoppedMerchantsInfo) {
            this.getRecommendedMerchantsAndRender();
          }
        }
      }.bind(this)).fail(function (error) {
        mn.log(error);
      });
    },
  return BecauseYouShopped;
});
```

And I need to export this parameter      `dataLimitForGetSimilarMerchant: 14,` to the Model of this Control for use it in `getSimilarMerchantData` function.
But when I importing it  - in way as You can see on the code here:

```
   define(['jquery', 'can', 'utils/promiseUtils', 'models/base', 'controls/base', 'coreMods/bonusComponents/becauseYouShopped/becauseYouShopped_control',], function ($, can, promiseUtils, BaseModel, BaseControl, BecauseYouShopped) {
  console.log("1 log: ", BecauseYouShopped);
  return BaseModel.extend({
    /**
     * Get response from one content group and type
     * @param contentGroupIdAndType
     * @returns {*}
     */
    getSimilarMerchantData: function (merchantId, merchantName) {
      var deferred = $.Deferred(),
        self = this;
      var controlOptions = BecauseYouShopped.defaults.dataLimitForGetSimilarMerchant;
      console.log("2 log: ", BecauseYouShopped);
      if (!merchantId) {
        return can.Deferred().reject('merchant id is not specified');
      }

      var options = {
        url: mn.contentAPIEndPoint + '/merchants/' + merchantId + '/similar',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: self.getAjaxHeaders(),
        data: self.getDefaultAjaxData({limit: controlOptions})
      };

  }, {});
});
```

I received that `BecauseYouShopped` is `undefined`

So, how can I import this parameter to the model?

Comment: Which version of CanJS are you using?  Also, are you using StealJS to manage dependencies?

Comment: CanJS - 2.3.4 without StealJS

Answer (score 0):

You have the BecauseYouShopped control importing the BecauseYouShopped model, but the model is also importing the control.  This sort of circular dependency can sometimes be resolved by your dependency manager if you are not trying to use the dependency module in-thread -- StealJS does this, for example -- but if you are using RequireJS like it seems you are based on the use of define(), you will need to require() one of your dependencies late rather than define()'ing it on initial load.  More on this at https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular

Comment: [Soapbox comment] it's generally bad form for models to directly import controls for things like defaults.  Is there a reason why the model can't have a property defining the default and the control import and use it?  This would prevent the circular dependency.

Comment: We can't hardcoded this limit property in model. All configurable things we store in defaults properties in controls.

Comment: Also I tried to use require()  - maybe I use it in wrong way  - but it doesn't work also.